# Why isn't " $ git log --graph " working

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, graph, logging

I've recently tried using branches in git but while they work allright whatever I do I can't display the graph of my branches and merges. I've tried Giggle for ubuntu and gitk -all but none of them works as shown in this nettuts+ tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-version-control-with-git/

I type in that

```
$ git log --graph #Sorry my sreenshot is missing h at the end
```

but instead of this...

[image]

...I get this...

[image: My output]

I would be really pleased with a quick reply...

Here is what ' $ gitk --all ' outputs

[image]

Comment: How do you expect it to look?  Are you sure you have a branch there?

Comment: You currently have `BigIdea` checked out. Maybe try `git log --graph master` instead to see `master`'s history (assuming you even merged `BigIdea` into `master`).

Comment: @TimBielawa Yes I have a branch here because checkout works and so does merge but it still displays just displays all branches in one line. I'm going to add a screenshot of what 'gitk -all' outputs...

Comment: @webdos it's possible that you're not getting a graph with a lot of different history paths because how of git works. In the interest of simplicity git does fast-forward (ff) merges when ever possible. An ff merge will just change the object the ref points at if the history will remain the same. That's probably why you're seeing what you are. Try making a branch off of master `git checkout -b testBranch`, making some commits, checking out master, `git merge --no-ff testBranch`, then `gitk --all`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for `git log --graph --all`, likewise with `gitk`, I have an alias in my shell:

```
alias gk='gitk --all'
```

for just that purpose.

From `git help log`

```
--all
    Pretend as if all the refs in refs/ are listed on the command line as <commit>.
```

So if you have branches `a`, `b`, and `c`, it's as if you told git to show the logs and graphs in this manner:

```
git log --graph a b c
```

Essentially, `git log` allows you to list any objets you can reference in what you want to see the logs for. You can even use it on a file, or multiple files files....

```
$ git log --oneline python-taboot.spec     
c96d546 Straighten out the Makefile. Hey -- make rpm works now! Update a lot of docs. Fixes #34 - Taboot 'edit' mode should hint at the file type and give instructi
ea0d60b Version bumpskies to 0.4.0-1beta
a95cfbf Automatic commit of package [python-taboot] release [0.3.2-1].
d9e3ca6 Make python-argparse a Requires for el6 as well
ea7ed54 Automatic commit of package [python-taboot] release [0.3.1-1].
69eaea9 Add conditional Requires on python-argparse. Update README and release notes.
...
```

And so on...